# Automate Quora scrolling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the Quora partners page https://www.quora.com/partners it loads the first 20 questions that you've written in the past. If you scroll to the bottom of the page, it loads the next 20.

I'm trying to automate scrolling until no more questions load with a tampermonkey script. Ideally this wouldn't jump to the bottom of the page repeatedly, but would rather run whatever function is running in the background simulating a scroll-to-bottom.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this or to identify what function is running in the background?

Comment: The chrome developer console can add breakpoints to eventlistener calls, so you start there.

Comment: Thanks. What event listeners should I add to?

Comment: scoll would be one, but maybe the site uses [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) then you could just search the code for it.

Comment: Looks like they might use the IntersectionObserver. Any idea how to hijack that in the Chrome console?

Comment: I never used it before, but if they are good programmers and the code isn't obfuscated they probably have a method as callback, but it could be an anonymous function directly defined in the observer construction. So you should look there